# How to tell which computer is connected to AirPlay

Tags: audio, airplay

My company shares a set of audio speakers accessible via AirPlay. Is there any way for someone to tell which computer is currently connected to the AirPlay without shouting the question out to the room?

Comment: Not 100% sure on this as I am unable to test myself however when you try to play to speakers that are already playing for someone else it used to/should warn you and I can't remember if it displays the name of the user who is already sharing.